# How to customize table size in github pages and sass template

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I have a [github pages website](http://hedge-ops.com) that is not rendering its tables at the desired size.

For example in [this post](http://hedge-ops.com/finding-alignment/) a table is rendered normally as:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Natural Alignment</th>
      <th>Natural Misalignment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Development</td>
      <td>Faster Delivery of features</td>
      <td>Have to be engaged in operations, more “work” to do</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Operations</td>
      <td>Less fires, more consistency</td>
      <td>Have to learn a new skillset and be a beginner</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Security</td>
      <td>More consistency, compliance</td>
      <td>Automation can cause unknown vulnerabilities</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Business</td>
      <td>Faster ROI for development, lower cost for operations, and a scale model that works</td>
      <td>Takes ongoing investment in culture and tools</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But it shows with a very small font. My sass is:

```
/**
 * Tables
 *
 */
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black
}

table {
    width: 100%
}

th, td {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5
}
```

[Here is the github repository with the jekyll site on it](https://github.com/mhedgpeth/mhedgpeth.github.io). Any idea how I can control the table size?

Comment: main css, line 966, add font-size: 3em; to table {
    background-color: transparent;
    }

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change it. Tried adding it to the main.scss [here](https://github.com/mhedgpeth/mhedgpeth.github.io/blob/master/_sass/_base.scss#L214)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove .table from your main css and replace it with table

table is intrinsic to html so to reference a body tag it's just body and not .body which is a class edit line 966

```
table {background-color: transparent;font-size: 3em;}
```

Comment: I'm going through _base.scss which is [here](https://github.com/mhedgpeth/mhedgpeth.github.io/blob/master/_sass/_base.scss#L214). I guess I don't know why that's not making it into the css as you say.

Comment: try adding class='table' to your table it will should pick up

Comment: That doesn't work either. I'm dealing with markdown conversion to the table so I don't have a lot of control either. I'm just surprised that I can't render it correctly.